# How to stop IntelliJ IDEA from forgetting ignored directories when using Gradle?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I have a Gradle project setup so it uses temporary directories with source files, so they have to be a part of a build process. But IDEA keeps forgetting I added those directories to ignored. I don't want to modify source files which get overwritten in next build - losing all changes I made, because IDEA navigated to a wrong file.

Gradle file for core module:

```groovy
import org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens

apply plugin: "java"
apply plugin: "scala"
sourceCompatibility = 1.6
[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'
def srcDirs = ["build/src/"]
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = ["src/"]
sourceSets.main.scala.srcDirs = srcDirs
eclipse.project {
    name = appName + "-core"
}
dependencies {
}

def getGitHash = { ->
    def stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    exec {
        commandLine 'git', 'rev-parse', '--short', 'HEAD'
        standardOutput = stdout
    }
    return stdout.toString().trim()
}

task prepareSources(type: Copy) {
    from('src')
    into('build/src')
    filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: [VERSION: version, GITHASH: getGitHash()])
}

compileScala {
    dependsOn prepareSources
}

compileScala.doLast {
    println("Deleting core jar")
    delete("/core/build/libs/core-1.0.jar")
}
```

It started after adding the token replacement (I don't know Gradle or Groovy much, it is all cobbled together, but it works).

Comment: try with Synchronize (ctrl + alt +y)

Comment: @NitinDhomse Doesn't seem to do anything. After restart of IDE all ignored directories are again marked as containing source files.

Comment: I guess that's because your gradle build files adds those directories to source sets. Can you show the relevant part of your build.gradle?

Comment: @NitinDhomse I have updated the question - added build file for core module (whole build is heavily based on libGDX setup).